# Collect doesn't work when I ask it to collect in terms of powers of (x−2) Part II

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying collect the following polynomial wich is factor of z-2 and z+2 it came from the series taylor of Sin(x) around two point x=2 and x =-2

```
(-2+z) z (2+z) (Cos[2]/8-Sin[2]/16)+(-2+z)^2 z (2+z)^2 (-((3 Cos[2])/128)-Sin[2]/256)+1/2 z Sin[2]
```

if you expand the series you get

```
-(7/8) z Cos[2]+5/16 z^3 Cos[2]-3/128 z^5 Cos[2]+11/16 z Sin[2]-1/32 z^3 Sin[2]-1/256 z^5 Sin[2]
```

but if you want to Collect as above using Collect you can not reverse the series
in power of (x-2)(x+2) it is possible to get it  in Mathematica Thanks anyway

Comment: Could do `Expand[PolynomialReduce[-(7/8) z Cos[2] + 5/16 z^3 Cos[2] - 
     3/128 z^5 Cos[2] + 11/16 z Sin[2] - 1/32 z^3 Sin[2] - 
     1/256 z^5 Sin[2], w - (z - 2), z][[2]]] /. w -> z - 2`

Comment: Daniel do not work the series express sum of (z-2)(z+2)

Comment: (1) Is `x` the same as `z`? If so, why not use just one of them? (2) My best guess at what you're seeking would be to replace `(z - 2)` in @Daniel's comment by `(z^2 - 4)` (in both places), or `(z-2)(z+2)`.  But then there's an extra factor of `z`, which is already apparent in your first code-expression. So getting a "series in power of (x-2)(x+2)", by which I think you mean a series in powers of `(z-2)(z+2)` does not seem possible

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Michael for your help